# grunt karma getting error .... Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
> >     Warning: Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

I'm experiencing this issue too.
I'm using node 7.5.0 and npm 4.1.2.

Comment: Are you npm installing grunt-karma, as well as karma?

Comment: Yes, my npm installing grunt-karma aswell

Comment: What versions of grunt-karma and karma are you installing?

Comment: "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",  and "karma": "^0.12.31"

Comment: I'm getting: Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
Warning: Task "karma" not found. Use --force to continue.

Answer (score 24):

I faced a similar problem. The following correction helped me

```
"grunt-karma": "^0.12.2",
"karma": "^1.6.0",
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/mcka-dev/ng-torrent-ui/commit/7716a2a9271dc8d9f8475630e634561f43920106)

Answer (score 2):

Doing npm install on karma helped me fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. 
First make sure grunt installed locally? otherwise you may see the following message:

*Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
If you're seeing this message, grunt hasn't been installed locally to
your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt,
please see the Getting Started guide:*

The whole workaround consists of the following steps, even though not all of these steps are necessary but just to be on the safe side:

Optionally, you can uninstall and re-install grunt. That applies to your entire PC and not just to the local installation. Once you uninstall grunt, it won't be accessible from other local folders.

```
npm uninstall -g grunt
```

then install the grunt command line by calling:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Installing a local instance of grunt:

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Now you can recreate *package.json* by calling:

```
npm init
```

Then fill (or confirm) all details and it will create a new *package.json* file. 
Then, for the grunt dependencies, call:

```
npm install
```

If there are errors or warnings, fix them by calling:

```
npm audit fix
```

or in severe cases:

```
npm audit fix --force
```